# Is there a video conferencing service that would support 12 people?

Tags: webapp-rec

I am looking for a free or affordable (i.e. closer to Skype or GoToMeeting than Cisco telepresence) video conferencing service that would handle 12 participants.

In case one doesn't exist, please list ones you know of with maximum allowed participants (e.g. OoVoo: up to six people).

Answer (score 1):

I've used a tool called BigBlueButton, which is a free (and open-source) conferencing tool.  It's still under development, but I'm in the process of integrating it into my office's extranet as a replacement for GoToMeeting.

It can act as a stand-alone tool (i.e., you download the VM and run the conferencing tool on your desktop or server for privacy), or you may be able to jump onto their "demo" site, and create yourself a private meeting for a short time.

BigBlueButton contains a combination of Asterisk, Red5, and may other tools, and is aimed at the educational market - it allows for uploading presentations, a whiteboard, and all participants can have a webcam active.

You can see the main website for it at:  http://bigbluebutton.org/

And the Google Code repository at:  http://code.google.com/p/bigbluebutton/

Answer (score 0):

Found [SightSpeed](http://www.sightspeed.com/multi-party-9), that will accomodate up to 9 people.

Comment: So are you looking for 12 participants in a conference or **up to** 12?

Comment: @Alex I am looking for 12, thus the question remains unanswered

Answer (score 0):

Skype now has [Group Video Calls](http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/features/allfeatures/group-video-calls/) feature, that accomodates up to 10 people.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most popular Google Plus features is "[Hangouts](http://www.mustseeon.net/social-network/google-plus-hangout-a-google-video-calling-service/)", which accommodate up to 10 people in a group video chat. And it's free.